# Unable to get proper timestamp ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I am hoping to generate a range of timestamps between:

> 18:00 (EST) on October 6th, 2014

and the same time **400** seconds later with an interval size of `2.2` seconds.

### Getting the start and end dates:

When I do the following:

```
start_time = datetime.datetime(year  = 2014, 
                               month = 10, 
                               day   = 6, 
                               hour  = 18, 
                               tzinfo = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
end_time   = start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=400)
```

Something seems to fail:

- `start_time.isoformat()` returns `'2014-10-06T18:06:40-04:56'`
- `end_time.isoformat()` returns `'2014-10-06T18:06:40-04:56'`

note that the time-zone offset for both timestamps above are: `-04:56` (4 hours and 56 minutes) even though EST is **5 hours** behind UTC. ?

### Getting the time range:

Moving forward, if I try to get a range of timestamps between these two dates every `2.2 seconds` (i.e. `2200 ms`):

```
ts = pd.date_range(start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='2200L')
```

I get:

```
> ts[0]
Timestamp('2014-10-06 18:56:00-0400', tz='US/Eastern', offset='2200L')
```

or in other words:

```
> ts[0].isoformat()
'2014-10-06T18:56:00-04:00'
```

which also does not make sense (note that the time is `18:56`, even though I was asking to get a range between `18:00` and `18:06:40` (i.e. `400` seconds after `18:00`)

Comment: whats the problem?what are you expecting? and how is what you are getting different from what you expect?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I updated the OP with the answers.

Comment: I got tired of dealing with Python's awkward datetime implementation (particularly with respect to timezones), and have started using http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/.  YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got tired of dealing with Python's awkward datetime implementation (particularly with respect to timezones), and have started using crsmithdev.com/arrow.  A solution using this lib:

```
import arrow

start_time = arrow.get(2014, 10, 6, tzinfo='US/Eastern')
end_time = start_time.replace(seconds=400)

print start_time.isoformat()
print end_time.isoformat()

# alternate form

start_time = arrow.get('2014-10-06T18:00:00.000-04:00')
end_time = start_time.replace(seconds=400)

print start_time.isoformat()
print end_time.isoformat()

# get a datetime from an arrow object
start_time_dt = start_time.datetime
```

Comment: Thanks -- Is there any way to convert the objects back to `datetime` (or anything else accepted by `pd.date_range`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import dateutil.parser as parser
import datetime
start_time = parser.parse("06/Oct/2015 18:00 EST")
end_time  = start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=400)
interval = datetime.timedelta(seconds=2.2)
current_time = start_time
while current_time < end_time:
     current_time += interval
     print current_time
```

but I probably dont understand what your issue is